# How do I create matrices with arbitrary list restrictions?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, pure-function

I want to randomly generate a square matrix of dimension n with entries in the list StartingEntries, and also satisfying that for any such matrix M, the matrix Inverse[IdentityMatrix[n] - M] has entries coming from the list EndingEntries.

Below is my (not-working) code for the case dimension 3.  It's the last line that keeps generating error messages.  I'd like to know why.  (Also if anyone can think of a better way of solving this problem, I'm all ears!)

```
(*generate 10,000 possible matrices.*)
mat = {{#1, #2, #3}, {#4, #5, #6}, {#7, #8, #9}} &
candidates = Apply[mat, RandomChoice[StartingEntries, {10000, 9}], 1]

(*get all matrices M so that I-M is invertible*)
invertibleCandidates = Select[candidates, Det[IdentityMatrix[3] - #] != 0 &]
```

So far so good.  Now we want to make sure that the inverted matrix has the correct entries.  I couldn't find a boolean Subset function in Mathematica, so I made my own:

```
SubsetQ[x_, y_] := (Length[Intersection[x, y]] == Length[x])
```

Now test to see if the inverse has entries lying inside EndingEntries.  This is the line that keeps failing on me and I don't know why.

```
newerCan = Select[invertibleCandidates, SubsetQ[Flatten[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[3] - #]], EndingEntries] &]
```

Edit 1: SubSetQ modified to be

```
SubsetQ[x_, y_] := (Length[Intersection[DeleteDuplicates[x], DeleteDuplicates[y]]] == Length[DeleteDuplicates[x]])
```

Edit 2: The error messages I'm getting are

```
DeleteDuplicates::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in DeleteDuplicates[nums].
Intersection::heads: Heads DeleteDuplicates and List at positions 2 and 1 are expected to be the same.
Inverse::luc: "Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix {{0.6,-0.7,-0.2},{-0.4,0.6,-0.1},{-0.2,-0.3,1.}} may contain significant numerical errors."
Inverse::sing: "Matrix {{0.7,-0.8,0.},{0.,0.9,-0.9},{-0.7,0.,0.8}} is singular."
```

I'm assuming that the first three error messages are because I'm not formatting the input to SubSetQ in the appropriate list format, but I don't know how to fix it, and I don't know why I'd be getting the "singular" error message.

Comment: It's just a guess but perhaps it's because all elements in the matrix `Flatten[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[3] - #]]` aren't unique? In that case `SubsetQ` returns false since `Intersection[{1,1,2},{1,2}]` is not `{1,1,2}` but `{1,2}`. The length of the list is two, not three.

Comment: @Anon, thanks, you definitely found a bug.  However that wasn't my main problem.  I edited the above to include the error messages I'm getting, which might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had two issues: one was that Mathematica was incorrectly identifying my matrices as "badly conditioned" just because the entries were decimals.  I changed them to fractions (of the same value) and those error messages went away.  Second, there was something wonky about my list formatting, and I still don't understand exactly what.  However, the following code is now working perfectly -- it's essentially the same as what's above, except that I keep everything as a 1-dimensional list, and use Partition to convert to a matrix when necessary, instead of keeping everything as a matrix and flattening to a list when necessary.

```
(*create our list of candidates*)
candidates = RandomChoice[StartingEntries, {10000, 9}]

(*identify the matrices M where I-M is invertible*)
invertible = Select[candidates, Det[IdentityMatrix[3] - Partition[#, 3]] != 0 &]

(*define the SubsetQ and ValidMatrix functions*)
SubsetQ[x_, y_] := Length[Intersection[DeleteDuplicates[x], DeleteDuplicates[y]]] == Length[DeleteDuplicates[x]]
ValidMatrix[x_] := SubsetQ[Flatten[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[3] - Partition[x, 3]]], EndingEntries]

(*select the ones where Inverse[I-M] have the appropriate entries*)
finalChoices = Select[invertible, ValidMatrix]

(*get one randomly*)
Partition[RandomChoice[finalChoices], 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

First evaluate `Inverse[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]` and you will see that the expression is not evaluated since the matrix is singular. This causes the first two error messages, because you're trying to execute `DeleteDuplicates` on an unevaluated (atomic) expression.

Because some matrices are badly conditioned, the values you get from those matrices won't be exact and hence they won't match the elements in `EndingEntries`, or they will match but it will be incorrect. That's one problem but it's not fatal, it just affect the detectability of certain matrices.

The error message `Inverse::sing: "Matrix {{0.7,-0.8,0.},{0.,0.9,-0.9},{-0.7,0.,0.8}} is singular."` is exactly what you wanted to avoid by checking the determinant. The reason it didn't work can be seen to be that:

```
Det[{{0.7, -0.8, 0.}, {0., 0.9, -0.9}, {-0.7, 0., 0.8}}]
```

> 7.99361*10^-17

That is, because of problems with precision, *Mathematica* reports this matrix to be non-singular. But in reality:

```
MatrixRank[{{0.7, -0.8, 0.}, {0., 0.9, -0.9}, {-0.7, 0., 0.8}}]
```

> 2

So that its determinant ought to have been zero, because this matrix is evidently singular.

You can either introduce a tolerance level and replace the condition `!=0` with `Abs[]>tolerance` or something like that. Or you can use this test: `MatrixRank[m]=n`. This should ensure that only truly non-singular/invertible matrices are selected into `invertibleCandidates`.